# Refresh Captcha Code with Updatepanel control in ASP>NET

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, captcha

I have a captcha code in my site.
sometimes needs to chenge that picture , but i dont want the whole page refreh.
i used updatepanel in this way :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"
                    ForeColor="Red" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtimgcode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/CImage.aspx" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Check" />


                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="refresh" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>  
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is Button3 code behind :

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/CImage.aspx";
    }
```

Button1 Works correctly But Button3 which should change the captcha picture doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

In addition if Iwant to use a refresh image instead of Button3,What controls should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image likely isn't updating during partial postback because the browser doesn't realize that the image content has changed since it been targeted to same page over and over. Adding querystring might help in this case one need to pass random id as querystring to the ImageUrl of the captcha.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image1.ImageUrl = string.Format("~/CImage.aspx?img={0}", Guid.NewGuid());
}
```

Comment: when the Button3  is out of the UpdatePanel works correctly but when i put it n UpdatePanel doesen't work

Comment: Have you tried my solution when button is inside update panel?

Comment: yes.and this error on UpdatePanel1.Update(); line appeare :
""The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' when UpdateMode is set to Conditional.""

Comment: Then remove that line and run again

Comment: If it is working properly then you can mark it as accepted :) . If you are new user check [How To](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code Kindly check if "~/CImage.aspx" is returning correct values or not. I have modified your code Kindly check:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"
                ForeColor="Red" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtimgcode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Image Width="100" Height="100" ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/CImage.aspx" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Check" />


            <asp:Button ID="Button3" OnClick="Button3_Click" runat="server" Text="refresh" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button3" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Image1.ImageUrl == "Koala.jpg")
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "Close.png";
    }
    else
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "Koala.jpg";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,But it doesn't work.. I mean I don't understand  your mean of "Koala.jpg" and  "Close.png" ?
What should i write instead of them?

Comment: Koala.jpg and close.png are just image names I have copied to project folder for testing. You can replace them with your image url.

Comment: I had already do what you say,but again it doesn't work.But when i get out the button3 from UpdatePanel it works correctly..